# Keep progressbar state on old state when navigation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

I have a problem when have created a progress bar for my template but when I navigate in routes pages my progress bar restarts itself and begin from 0. I have tried many methods but have no success, like localStorage and move it to high level component. This is my code:

```js
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import LinearProgress, { linearProgressClasses } from '@mui/material/LinearProgress';
import DepositContext from "../Deposit/PaymentWindows/DepositContext";
import { styled } from "@mui/material";

const ProgressBarTimer = () => {
  const { delayCount } = useContext(DepositContext);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleProgress = () => {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setProgress((prevProgress) =>
          prevProgress === 100 ? 0 : prevProgress + 1
        );
      }, delayCount);
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    };

    handleProgress();
  }, [delayCount]);
```

Comment: Please [edit] to include a ***complete*** [mcve] so we can see what the code around `ProgressBarTimer` is doing when a navigation action is effected.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this solved your problem but the clear interval code is incorrect

```
 useEffect(() => {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setProgress((prevProgress) =>
          prevProgress === 100 ? 0 : prevProgress + 1
        );
      }, delayCount);
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [delayCount]);
```

You can you a global state management and move "progress" into a global state. I recommended jotai

Comment: That part of the OP's code is mostly fine, they just need to `return handleProgress();` so the cleanup function is returned by the hook callback.